# "Cannot Find Symbol" even though classes are in the same package

Tags: java, package

I am trying to run a java class that extends another class. When I compile them with javac *.java I don't have any problems. When I run the Test class, it works. However, when I try the TestExtend class, I get the following error:

TestExtend.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
symbol: variable Test
location: class TestExtend

Here are my two classes:

```
package test1;

public class Test {

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("I am here aswell");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        test();
    }
}
```

the extended class:

```
package test1;

public class TestExtend extends Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Test.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you're compiling the code. My guess is that you're doing it from the `test1` directory, which means the compiler doesn't know where to find the `Test.java` file. If you compile from the directory *above* `test1`, e.g. `javac test1/TestExtend.java`, it should work. Ultimately I'd recommend using an IDE though - that will hide all the build complexities from you.

Comment: Oh my god, now I see it! Thank you so much, can't believe that the solution was so simple...